# Python how to create one plot with boxplot of verctors with different length

Tags: python, graph, visualization, seaborn, boxplot

I have two lists with different length:

```
l1 = [1,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,8,9,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,8,9,5,9,8,7,3,5,8,6]
l2 = [0,1,2,3,4,6,1,2,8,2,3,1,3,4,4,1,2,2,3,9,1,2,0,0,0,1]
```

I want to create one plot with box/violin plot such they will be next to eachother. 
How can I do it eventhough they differ in length?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, it should be as simple as you draw plots with equal lenght vectors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

l1 = [1,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,8,9,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,8,9,5,9,8,7,3,5,8,6]
l2 = [0,1,2,3,4,6,1,2,8,2,3,1,3,4,4,1,2,2,3,9,1,2,0,0,0,1]

fig, ((mpl_box_ax, sns_box_ax), (mpl_violin_ax, sns_violin_ax)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)

mpl_box_ax.boxplot([l1, l2])
mpl_violin_ax.violinplot([l1, l2])

sns.boxplot(data=[l1, l2], ax=sns_box_ax)
sns.violinplot(data=[l1, l2], ax=sns_violin_ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]